# matrix node with same attribute transformation to matrix in igraph

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

[image]
I have a matrix in igraph, as the 1st in the above pic. The numbers mean cooperation times. I have a attibute, as the 2nd. I would like a code that can automatically give me the 3rd matrix in igraph or other in R. Thx in adavnce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Non-`igraph` approach

You can try the code below (don't need `igraph`)

```
> +((with(a, outer(type, type, `==`)) * mat) > 0)
  A B C
A 0 0 1
B 0 0 0
C 1 0 0
```

---

## `igraph` approach

If you want to use `igraph` anyway, one possible option might be

```
graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat > 0, mode = "undirected") %>%
    get.data.frame() %>%
    filter(a[from, ] == a[to, ]) %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE, vertices = row.names(a)) %>%
    get.adjacency(sparse = FALSE)
```

which gives

```
  A B C
A 0 0 1
B 0 0 0
C 1 0 0
```

## Data

```
mat <- `dimnames<-`(
    matrix(c(0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0), 3),
    rep(list(LETTERS[1:3]), 2)
)

a <- `rownames<-`(data.frame(type = c("edu", "company", "edu")), LETTERS[1:3])
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have another question.

Comment: @JovieChuang What question?